# C++ Server multi client logging with boost

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-asio

long time reading, first time posting.

I dont't know if it is maybe stupid, but I want to build a "simple" Server/Client for logging multiple Application in one point.
All with boost.

- Server writes to log file (that is no Problem, working good with boost log)
- Server should accept multiple clients/applications
- there should not be a new connection for each log msg, I think this would lead into a lot overhead in create connections

I have a working server/client with boost asio tcp ip iostream, but only to open connectin, send the msg and after it closeing the connection. This works fine with 2 applications-
But as I said, this leads in a big overhead in opening connections.

Anyone has a good idea to accomplish idea, in open the connection only once for each apllication?

Comment: what is the problem with opening a connection and sending a log to a server? You do not have to close it after sending one message. If you run  your application with docker and can ssh into the system: you could ssh into the system and use docker logs to check the logs (things this application wrote to stdout). So you do not need to change your application to get the logs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.